# Video game based around the Turing test where optional information says that you never interacted with any humans to begin with

Tags: story-identification, video-games, artificial-intelligence

A friend and I are looking for a video game based around the Turing test, where you can find or discover an audiolog or text or something (not sure) that reveals that the whole time there were no humans, only AI/robots interacting with the main character.
It it not necessary for the story, so you can miss it, but finding it gives the whole story and another dimension.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you play this? Was it a PC game or a console game? If a console game, which console did you play it on? Were the graphics in 2D or 3D? If in 3D, then was the game world viewed from a first-person or third-person perspective?

Comment: There's a *BioShock 2* single-player module (DLC) called "[Minerva's Den](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BioShock_2:_Minerva%27s_Den)" where it turns out the player's controller is really a Turing AI, but the antagonists aren't all AIs.

Comment: Is this The Turing Test - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Turing_Test_(video_game)

Comment: @A.Steer it is not for none of us had heard of the game before looking for the answer ^^"

Comment: This rings a bell for me. Maybe it's a quest in Fallout 4 though. Like the covenant settlement or something else. But that trope is prevalent in video games. It also _kind of_ happens in No Man's Sky. 0b10000.

Comment: Was the main character actually a human, or yet another AI?

Comment: In System Shock 2 you are interacting with a doctor woman and maybe a few others only to discover later that all those people are actually an AI.

Comment: Another contender: [The Talos Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Talos_Principle) (which influenced the video game The Turing Test).